# How to show numeric only keypad in mobile browser along with maxlength & not allow keypad special characters?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I have few fields for which I need numeric keypad to show up in mobile browser.

`<input type="tel">` shows up keypad but along with it comes the special characters like ( ) p w + etc.

`<input type="number">` shows up keypad but there is no maxlength support. One of the field is age. So it's width is very small.

Since maxlength support is not present: If user enters too many characters, validation will happen but erasing the big number becomes tedious due to small input size.

Comment: Is the answer okay? Are you looking for something that I've missed?

Comment: My bad. I did not mention about the browser validations not to be used. We need to show a small error message below the field consistently across browsers. (Browser validation UI are not consistent across.) I found the solution btw.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `pattern` attribute that you can use instead of `max-length`. So the form will instantly validate the pattern and flag an error if not satisfied. For example,

```
<input type="tel" pattern="^\d{1,4}$">
```

This will only accept a number of length lesser that 4 (i.e between 1 and 4). It flags if the length exceeds or the user enters an invalid character like `#`.

I've tested it on Firefox and its working.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following method

Method 1:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" inputmode="numeric" />
```

Method 2 (good for phone number):

```
<input type="tel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution using `<input type="tel">`. The special characters from the telephonic keypad return **229** as keycode. And parsing the value to integer returns as **NaN**. Thereby helping to validate the character entered.

One peculiar issue with Chrome in Android is you don't get key events. So you will be able to enter special characters but will be validated later. In other browsers, you won't be able to enter special characters at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use, an input `type='number'` with max and min attributes.

```
<input type="number" id="age" min="0" max="999" />
```

Or if you prefer use Javascript, in an event KeyPress.

```
<input type="number" id="age" min="0" max="999" onkeypress="validateLength()"/>

<!-- language: lang-js -->

const limitAgeSize = 3;
const $inputAge = document.getElementById("age");
function validateLength() {
    if ($inputAge.value.length >= limitAgeSize) {
        $inputAge.value = $inputAge.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
```

The problem is if a user Copy for example "99999" and press `Ctrl + V`, the function `validateLength()` only will delete the last character. For delete more, you can write a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply define text field type number and set max lengt 3 **

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/spdtxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:text="80" />
```